Visual Studio 2022 - IIS 10 - Unable to start debugging on the web server - Timeout

I'm trying to start Asp.Net 4.8 WebApplication in Debug Mode in Visual Studio 2022 environment on IIS 10
In the image you can see the problem.
Here what i've already tried:

iisreset
recreate AppPool
set iis start timeout from 90 to 900
reinstall IIS
Repair/reinstall VS2022
Delete .vs folder
Deactivate VS Extensions
Deactivate Diagnostic tools
Check Website folder permission access
Try to Attach Process later but another error is triggered


I don't know where to turn.
UPDATE
If i try to run Debug multiple times, after 3-4 consecutive tries, debug starts correctly.
So what happens then.
When it works, i see 2-3 chrome (no matter which browser is) opened (one for each try) and if i close one of them (no matter which) debugger is detached.
So weird.

You will have to run a report to reveal the important settings, https://docs.lextudio.com/jexusmanager/tutorials/vs-diagnostics as others cannot guess what's wrong on your machine from merely some words and screen shots.

1.Unable to start debugging on the Web server this error occurs because an error or configuration change has occurred.Reset IIS and retry debugging. Multiple debugger instances may be attached to the IIS process; a reset terminates them.
Check IIS configuration

Make sure that the correct version of ASP.NET is installed on IIS.



Check your Application Pool configuration, correct it if needed.

Update the ASP.NET version in the Application Pool and restart it.

Check that your Web Application folder has the right permissions.

Make sure that you give IIS_IUSRS, IUSR, or the specific user associated with the Application Pool read and execute rights for the Web Application folder.
Other causes

Restart Visual Studio with Administrator privileges and try again.
If multiple instances of Visual Studio are running, reopen your project in one instance of Visual Studio.

For more information, see Error: Unable to Start Debugging on the Web Server
2.Failed to launch debug adapter Try disabling Script Debugging from IIS as below shown.

